# Sound waves in and out of phase

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A sound ray is emitted from a point source and is then reflected off of a flat surface onto a detector. The reflection shifts the sound wave by 0.5 wavelengths. What does the shifting mean?

Comment: Given the context, can you write what you think it means?

Comment: The about "phase".

Answer (score 1):

Each wave source has an initial phase.When a wave is incident on a surface some or all part of it is is reflected off the surface.It so happens that the medium changes the phase difference by some quantity. For instance if you add any quantity to the graph of a particular function(you may want to google it) the graph tends to shift backward or forward as per the nature of the added quantity. Similarly in sound waves , when they fall on a surface a particular phase is imparted to them and thus they tend to shift. This graph will serve the purpose I hope!

[image]